# Small error getting to me sqrt function

Tags: c, error-handling

I am writing this program to find the square root of a number. While defining the function mysqrt(). I am using the Newton-Raphson method. in the if() I use fabs(blah data blah) < 0.001 for relative error EX. if error is less than .1% the answer is correct. When I compile the code below

I get error line 27: called object '5.0e-1' is not a function.

I am absolutely lost as to what it is referring to. Please help Thank you.

I know there is a sqrt() function but this is for an extra credit assignment I have the majority of it written but cannot correct this error.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    double mysqrt(double a);

    int main()
    {
     double a, result;

     printf("Enter a number to find the square root of: ");
     scanf("%d", &a);

     result = mysqrt(a);

     printf("The square root of %d is %d \n", a, result);
    }


    double mysqrt(double num)
    {
     double x, new_x;
     if((fabs(((x+1) - x)/(x+1)))<0.001)
     {
      for(x=2; x != num;)
      {
       new_x=(x+1);
       new_x=(0.5(x+(num/x)));
       x=new_x;
      }
     }
        else
       {
        return new_x;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot multiplication sign here:

```
new_x=(0.5(x+(num/x)));
```

This is a quite common error and when you see "... is not a function.", it means somewhere you have ...() which is most often a forgotten multiplication.

Also your program hard to read because of lots of parentheses, why not to write:

```
new_x = 0.5 * (x + num/x);
```

In addition, this:

```
(fabs(((x+1) - x)/(x+1))) < 0.001
```

is equivalent to:

```
fabs(1/(x+1)) < 0.001
```

Do your simplifications on paper, it will make your program more readable and errors easier to spot.